# C++ initialize member variables with { }

Tags: c++, class

Recently I have seen member variable initialization in c++ as such:

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo();
private:
    bool bar{false};
};
```

What is the point of variable initialization like this/how does member variable declaration/definition like this differ or not differ from using an initialization list as such:

```
foo::foo() : bar(false) {}
```

Comment: What would be your best guess?

Comment: Based on seeing usages and what information I could find about it it seems like it gives a default value? But then how is that, in a sense, different from giving it a default value in an initialization list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useful when you have a lot of constructors. `bool bar{false};` means set bar to false unless the constructor initialises it to something else. it's just for convenience

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization for a more detailed explanation